# Is the passive form of the word "theme" correct in this sentence?

Tags: passive-voice, verb-forms

Recently we were given the task to promote the upcomong conference at our university, so I wrote the twitter post: "getting excited for this year´s conference themed Terrorism" Is it gramatically correct?

Comment: I would prefer: "getting excited about this year's conference". I would use "for" in a sentence referring to a person: "I am excited for you as you enter the final round".

Answer (score 1):

English has a long history of using nouns as verbs—*verbing* nouns, as it were.

If the conference had terrorism as its theme, it is unobjectionable to say that it was "themed Terrorism."

For more illumination, see this ELU blog article from a few years ago, titled [The Give That Keeps On Gifting](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/12/the-give-that-keeps-on-gifting-the-protean-nature-of-english-words-and-why-thats-a-good-thing/).

(And do notice the verbing of "title" in the previous sentence.)

Comment: the theme of the conference is terrorism, so what would you suggest me to say?

Comment: I'm saying it's fine to say that the conference was "themed terrorism" ...

Comment: oh, ok, got it:)

Comment: ...but even better might be _"the upcoming terrorism-themed conference."_